# How to set color of row and add image to cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render

I want to change color of row so I create my own cell renderer:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    if (row % 2 == 1) {
        setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
    }
    if (row % 2 == 0) {
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
```

this works fine until I want to add image to cell so I override method in table:

```
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        if (column == 4) {
            return ImageIcon.class;
        }
        return Object.class;
    }
```

Now the fourth column is still white and doesn't change color.

How I can implement all this things simultaneously?

Thx for advise

Comment: And how are you setting the JTable's default renderer? Can we see the code where you add the renderer to the table or Column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to change color of row

Overriding the `prepareRender(...)` method of the `JTable` allows you to customize rendering for the entire row without providing custom renderers.

The basic logic would be something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable( model )
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  Alternate row color

        if (!isRowSelected(row))
            c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? getBackground() : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        return c;
    }
};
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and working examples.

Note, you still need to override the `getColumnClass()` method to display your `Icon`.